# flutter: using MVVM, provider, http, dependency injection and repository pattern, error

Tags: flutter, mvvm, dependency-injection, flutter-provider

[this is my flutter app file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COOA7.png)

i am trying to uses the mvvm structure but i keep coming ap on an error message

Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. for my di code

```
final personsRepoProvider = Provider<PersonsRepository>(create:(ref) => PersonsRepositoryImpl());

final homeViewModelProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<HomeViewModel>(create:
      (ref) => HomeViewModel(ref.read(personsRepoProvider)),
);
```

my view model looks like this

```
class HomeViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  late TextEditingController nameController;
  late TextEditingController surNameController;
  final PersonsRepository _personsRepository;

  HomeViewModel(this._personsRepository) {
    nameController = TextEditingController();
    surNameController = TextEditingController();
  }

  Future<bool> saveToDatabase() async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'name': nameController.text,
      'surName': surNameController.text,
    };

    return await _personsRepository.saveUserData(data);
  }
}
```

and my main is this

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        personsRepoProvider,
        homeViewModelProvider,
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

so why am i getting this error?